# prevent browser back button caching without using no-store

Tags: php, html, laravel, browser, webbrowser-control

Currently on the site, to prevent back button caching, we are using no-store header in response headers. However, we are leaving a lot of potential performance improvement on the table by completely killing the cache like that.
Ideally, I want to use a last-modified header, and I want the browser to constantly revalidate the data, even on the back button. But it seems even with must-revalidate and last-modified header, the back button on the browser does not fire a request and simply falls back on cache.

Is there a way to keep it from doing that on the back button without using no-store?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't had success disabling the back button in Chrome using no-store. Seems to cache anyway. Chrome 111.0.5563.146

Comment: Yes, same. When I paused the question I was going for a shotgun approach for all my site. I have since given up and decided I should treat each page separately.